# IdentityServer4 Hybrid Flow Token Refresh with SignalR

Tags: asp.net, signalr, identityserver4

My legacy .Net app is using OIDC with IdentityServer4 (well, IdentityServer3 assemblies) to handle my tokens. Everything is working fine except when I'm on a view that refreshes often or has constant interaction with my SignalR API. When the token refreshes, it's not the greatest user experience. If any ajax calls are executing or my SignalR connection is reconnecting, everything errors out.

What's the best approach to handle this situation? I thought about cancelation tokens but I don't have any experience working with them. Currently, I'm catching these in my error callbacks and just waiting a few to retry. Not sure if that's the best approach.